# Polynom in Mathematica API with Android application-Cloud

Tags: android, android-studio, math, cloud, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to create an android application that gets a polynom as an input and returns the Roots of this as a result, through a connection with a Mathematica API (cloud). I have created a Mathematica API and got the URL in order to create a link on the cloud.

The API I have created is this:

```
api3=APIFunction[{"x"->"Polynom"},RootIntervals[{#x},Complexes]&,"String"];
CloudDeploy[api3, Permissions->"Public"]
```

My code on Android application is the one below:

```
public class test extends ActionBarActivity implements CloudInterface {

private EditText field;
private ProgressBar bar;
private TextView text;

private String baseURL = "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/cc82c3e5-3ac3-4272-aea6-d5d3505e79a9";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field);
    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void buttonClick(View v) {

    bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    text.setText("");

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(field.getWindowToken(), 0);

    Double num = 0.0;
    if(!field.getText().toString().equals(""))
        num = Double.valueOf(field.getText().toString());

    CloudCompute cc = new CloudCompute(this);
    cc.execute(num);
}


@Override
public void onEvaluateCompleted(String result) {

    bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (result.endsWith("."))
        result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "result  " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    text.setText(result);
}

@Override
public String getBaseURL() {
    return baseURL;
}
```

}

The applications stops its function when I push the button to get the result. The error it shows, is in line

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>              
>  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
>               
>  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4658)
>               
>  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19461)
>               
>  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               
>  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               
>  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>               
>  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5694)
>               
>  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>              
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>              
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>              
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>              
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>              
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>              
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>              
>   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
>               
>  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4658)
>               
>  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19461)
>               
>  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               
>  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               
>  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>              
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5694)
>              
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>              
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>              
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>              
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>              
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       
>   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "x^3-7*x+7"
>              
>   at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>              
>   at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:269)
>              
>   at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
>              
>   at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:332)
>              
>   at user.mathlab.Tautotites.buttonClick(test.java:69)
>              
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>            
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             
>    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
>              
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4658)
>              
>   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19461)
>              
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>              
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>              
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>              
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5694)
>              
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>             
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>              
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

How can I solve this? Have I done something wrong with the API? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you add your complete stacktrace?

Comment: @MartinRevert Yes, of course. I edited my question. Tell me if this helps you, or if I need to enter something else.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "x^3-7*x+7"` <--- You are trying to get a formula from an EditText as a double. There's no formula type in Java. If the API is a web service most probably you must send a String.

Comment: @MartinRevert Thank you for your help!! But could you please give me some more details? I am new on applications. The API is a web service. Should I send a string on the API or there is a problem in the application's code?

Comment: a) Your `num' variable is created with a Double type, so it only receives Double precision numbers, not functions or formulas. You could try changing it to String. b) I don't know the Mathematica API implementation, but probably it could receive a text String, but be careful with the format the API receives and also you are not sending an HTTP request after pressing the button. I recommend to read about how to code a web service client in Android before going in more deep waters.